# ValueError: Invalid literal for int() with base 10 when retrieving data with date from table with python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, date

Similar questions have been asked, but I didn't find an answer to this specific problem.

I have a flask application that shall retrieve data from a table called rates. The table is defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE rates (
                  id TEXT NOT NULL,
                  pc INTEGER,
                  collection_date DATE NOT NULL,
                  metercount INTEGER NOT NULL,
                  rate REAL        
                  )
```

Here is a small excerpt of the data in csv format:

```
SAG0990000000434;4151;2021-08-31 08:00:00;18;100.0
SAG0990000012332;;2021-08-31 08:00:00;40;100.0
SAG0990000000443;4220;2021-08-31 08:00:00;41;100.0
SAG0990000000552;4240;2021-08-31 08:00:00;63;100.0
SAG0990000000156;4360;2021-08-31 08:00:00;32;100.0
SAG0990000000527;4170;2021-08-31 08:00:00;1;100.0
SAG0990000000159;4022;2021-08-31 08:00:00;3;100.0
SAG0990000000429;4072;2021-08-31 08:00:00;75;100.0
SAG0990000003987;4251;2021-08-31 08:00:00;49;100.0
SAG0990000000269;4360;2021-08-31 08:00:00;83;100.0
```

I initialized the sqlite db connection with parse_decltypes and I am also very sure that I only stored my dates as python datetime objects and not as strings.

```
def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES|sqlite3.PARSE_COLNAMES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db



@bp.route('/dc_history', methods=['GET'])
def dc_history():
    db = get_db()
    dc = request.args.get('dc')
    dcdata = db.execute("select id, pc, collection_date, metercount, rate from rates where id = ?", (dc,)).fetchall()
    print(dcdata)
    return render_template('dash/dc_history.html', dcdata = dcdata)
```

When executing the sql query I get an Error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'16 08:00:00'`

Because of the "08:00:00" I suspect that the issue is about converting a sqlite date back to a datetime object in the sqlite 3 library. The exception occurs there:

> File "C:......\Python\Python38\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 64, in
> convert_date return datetime.date(*map(int, val.split(b"-")))

The problem is I don't see anything unusal when inspecting the data. Also the query works perfectly well in DB Browser for SQLite. Also I didn't find any occurence of '16 08:00:00'.

Comment: Note that the second column "pc" is sometimes NULL. But I don't think that this causes a problem, it would be converted by python to a Nonetype in the list

Comment: Looks like you've declared the column to be DATE, but inserted DATETIME values into it; unlike most databases, sqlite doesn't enforce types. The library is then attempting to convert it as the declared DATE type even though it's actually a DATETIME.

Comment: There are values ​​of different data types here, we cannot apply the same process (parsing)for all of them.

Comment: Thanks Jiri Baum for pointing this out. I tried to change the type to DATETIME with DB Browser for SQLite. But that didn't help. Then I tried using the date() function in my select statement, this gives me the date. I'm on the right way now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had to use the DATE() or DATETIME() function in my SELECT statement otherwise the sqlite3 library wouldn't know how to parse the data.

```
dcdata = db.execute("select id, pc, datetime(collection_date) collection_date, metercount, rate from rates where id = ?", (dc,)).fetchall()
```